# Calculation with uint

Tags: c#

I have code for calculation uint number from string input

When I give input text like "X1_Lore_Realmwalker" giving "1960749072" and this is correct number but when I give another text "Lore_AzmodansOrders1" giving 2909223662 but this number not correct, should be -1385743634 but this program not calculating correct value

```
            uint HashLowerCase(string input)
            {
                input = input.ToLowerInvariant();
                uint hash = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                    hash = (hash << 5) + hash + input[i];
                return hash;                

            }
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `should be -1385743634` How do you expect it should be represented in `uint`?

Comment: Should be : int HashLowerCase(string input)

Comment: The value you are reading is not a valid uint. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types for a list of available types. Probably what you are looking for is `int`, and not `uint`

Answer (score 1):

`uint` is unsigned integer, you can't make it hold negative numbers. Change all `uint` to `int` (method signature and `hash` variable type).